# Download vs Install in

Tags: cocoapods

In this example:

https://cocoapods.org/pods/Alamofire

What is Downloads and what is Installs? What action counts for download vs install?

And what are these categories under Install: 
Pod Tries, Test Targets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find out the answers on the CocoaPods blog announcing the stats: http://blog.cocoapods.org/Stats/

Comment: So downloads is basically each time the user does pod install or update?